# In the comics, have any of the Robins called their costume "target attraction" for villains?

Tags: dc, comics, titans-2018

In Season 1 Episode 6, "Jason Todd", of the live-action *Titans* (2018) series, the new Robin (Jason Todd) rescues Dick at Dr. Adamson's apartment. In the conversation between them that followed, Dick says:

> **Dick**: He lets you drive the Batmobile? Wouldn't you rather have your own name? Like "Sparrow" or "Blue Jay," for "Jason"?
>
> **Jason**: Fuck, no. The whole point is being Robin. Batman needs Robin.
>
> **Dick**: **Why do you think he makes us wear those lame colors? 'Cause we're drawing fire.
>   "Look over here, assholes!"** Then boom, the Bat lands and starts trashing ass.
>   
>   <sub>*Titans: Season 1 Episode 6 ("Jason Todd")*</sub>

Was this comment by Dick, taken/inspired from the comics where Dick (or any other Robin) said something similar?

Looking for the story arc where this happened.

Comment: I recall a comic in which Batman comments that he wears a bright yellow oval on his chest because it's easier to armor his chest than the cowl

Comment: Reminds me of the joke:
Why does Batman wear dark colors? So he doesn't get shot.
Why does Robin wear bright colors? Same reason.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is some complaint by Dick Grayson to Batman in *Grayson: Futures End* and he does state something similar to what is said above in *Titans*. Batman also gives a nice explanation for *why* Robin should wear bright clothing rather than the dark that he wears.

> [image: Grayson: Future's End comic page quoted below]
>   <sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>
>
> **Robin:** It's a little, I don't know, **bright**. I mean, you get to wear all the black stuff. You get to use the night and the shadows and things. Won't everyone, like, see me out there?
>
> **Batman:** Do you know how to use the shadows and the night?
>
> **Robin:** No, but --
>
> **Batman:** You wear black, you rely on the dark. It becomes your crutch. Someone takes it from you, and you fall.
>
> **Batman:** Wear *your* outfit so they *will* see you. Then beat them when they see you. When you're ready, wear *mine*. Earn the night.
>
> <sub>*Grayson: Future's End*</sub>

Comment: Robin: *"Why can you wear black if I can't?"* Batman: *"Becase I'm **Batman**!"*

Comment: Robin's lucky his suit isn't made out of entirely day-glow fabric like construction workers.  With those shoes that have blinking LEDs in them.  And jingly bells all over it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Sounds like a setup for a sketch. "Regulation-compliant Batman & Robin".